# Setting different outbound IP-Address per web Application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, tcp

My problem is that I have a Windows Server 2012 IIS with multiple web Application (WCF-Services).

I need to have different outbound IP-Address for each web Application.
Of course the machine have multiple IP-Addresses installed.

After extensive Googling a lean that I can set default outbound IP-Address using Netsh.exe but this won’t help me. I also start relishing that this probably isn’t possible with IIS and Windows Server 2012 alone.

Please, I need help with the best way to solve this problem. 
Please don’t suggest installing a secondary machine if this is isn’t the absolute only solution.

Comment: Then you need to enumerate through the End points in all you application to find the appropriate IP address if you applications are initiating the connection.  If the connections are started externally, the routing in the computer will automatically send to the correct IP provided the IP address and Masks are correctly configured on you IIS (no overlaps of IP and mask).

Comment: What do you mean by outbound? Are you making outbound TCP connections? What does this have to do with IIS?

Comment: Each web application reserves traffic on different IP-addresses in the IIS (This works fine). 
But for outgoing traffic, IIS always use the same IP-Address.   I need to send on different outgoing address depending on from with Web application I sending.